# jquery - cant move a list element back from the right side dunno why

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Left List</h1>
        <ul id="left-list">
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Right List</h1>
        <ul id="right-list">
            <li>TEST</li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


$('#left-list li').on('click', function () {
    $(this)
        .appendTo($('#right-list'))
        .unbind('click');
})

$('#right-list li').on('click', function () {
    $(this)
        .appendTo($('#left-list'))
        .unbind('click');
})
```

It just stays on one side after moving once x: what can i do? to fix this?
i want to move from left to right, and those which got moved to the right side, back to the left side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to catch the dynamic DOM updates. You can added the listener to the `document` instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#left-list li', function()..

$(document).on('click', '#right-list li', function()...
```

Or, even better, wrap your `box` elements in a parent element, and target that instead:

```js
$('.boxes').on('click', '#left-list li', function() {
  $(this).appendTo($('#right-list'));
})

$('.boxes').on('click', '#right-list li', function() {
  $(this).appendTo($('#left-list'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Left List</h1>
    <ul id="left-list">
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Right List</h1>
    <ul id="right-list">
      <li>TEST</li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the difference between (document) and (document.body), i tried both, both works

Comment: `body` is an element _within_ `document`. Spectric has simply placed the listener on the body instead of the document. Both are valid answers. `document` is convenient, but adding the listener on the closest parent element is a good idea too.

Comment: Event delegation works because events from children bubble up the DOM. You can place one listener on a parent element to "catch" them instead of attaching listeners to all the children.

Comment: aaah oke i kinda understand now, uhm so i should use (document.body) because its better right?

Comment: It's entirely up to you.

Comment: is there any benefit? of (document.body)

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event handler only works on the `li` elements that were originally in `#right-list`, not newly appended elements. You can either add an event listener on the newly appended element, or use event delegation.

Event delegation example:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '#left-list li', function() {
  $(this)
    .appendTo($('#right-list'))
    .unbind('click');
})
$(document.body).on('click', '#right-list li', function() {
  $(this)
    .appendTo($('#left-list'))
    .unbind('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Left List</h1>
  <ul id="left-list">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Right List</h1>
  <ul id="right-list">
    <li>TEST</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: omg it worked, can u explain it so i can understand it? would be great if possible

Comment: @Mosoli Is there any reason you accepted Andy's answer and not mine? His answer is nearly exactly the same as mine.